# Problems updating the database

Tags: database, vb.net, dataset

I have attached code for reference. I am trying to create database for my project details. I have currently 2 forms:

1. main form
2. project detail form

Main form used to switch various forms

Project detail forms are meant for add / edit / load project details

My main form in visual basic look like this.

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub

    Private Sub Bt_Project_Details_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bt_Project_Details.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Project_Details_Form.Show()
    End Sub
End Class
```

My project detail form look like this.

```
Public Class Project_Details_Form

    Private Sub Project_Details_Form_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        'TODO: This line of code loads data into the 'Project_Data_Set.Project_Data_Table' table. You can move, or remove it, as needed.
        Me.Project_Data_TableTableAdapter.Fill(Me.Project_Data_Set.Project_Data_Table)
    End Sub

    Private Sub Bt_Load_Project_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bt_Load_Project.Click
    End Sub

    Private Sub Bt_Cancel_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Bt_Cancel.Click
        Me.Hide()
        Form1.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click
        Project_Data_TableBindingSource.AddNew()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Project_Data_TableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Project_Data_TableBindingNavigatorSaveItem.Click
        Me.Validate()
        Me.Project_Data_TableBindingSource.EndEdit()
        Me.TableAdapterManager.UpdateAll(Me.Project_Data_Set)
    End Sub

    Private Sub BindingNavigatorDeleteItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorDeleteItem.Click
        Project_Data_TableBindingSource.RemoveCurrent()
    End Sub

    Private Sub FillByToolStripButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Try
            Me.Project_Data_TableTableAdapter.FillBy(Me.Project_Data_Set.Project_Data_Table)
        Catch ex As System.Exception
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub
End Class
```

Now I am facing a few problems:

1. Whenever I run the program, try to enter first entry data being saved but with empty value. The data enter next time being stored properly. How can make my first entry visible?
2. In below code:

   ```
   Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click
       Project_Data_TableBindingSource.AddNew()

   End Sub
   ```

   I am using `AddNew()`. This working fine, but problem is even I don't enter data like date, name kept empty, data recorded in their position is store empty only. I would like to say if any of project data set is empty give error message (since it mandatory for user to enter those data)

Comment: If you are asking about VB (actually VB.NET; just Visual Basic is assumed to be the old VB6, before .NET), why are you adding a VBA tag (a completely different language)? Tag your question properly and better don't add (inaccurate) references to the programming language in the title.

Comment: i am beginner. I am writing code in visual basic.

Comment: @varocarbas what made you think i have misbehave here.I have posted my code. i expect fact that it does meet the requirement of question to be asked

Comment: In your `Project_Data_TableBindingNavigatorSaveItem_Click` sub you need to check whether any data was added before saving.

Answer (score 0):

Is there any other method where i can assign value individually .
Like my Project database contain  project name, customer name  etc. if i say new button pressed clear all field. Once form filled individual value being record once save button pressed

```
Private Sub BindingNavigatorAddNewItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BindingNavigatorAddNewItem.Click
        Project_Data_TableBindingSource.AddNew()
    End Sub
```